# openpyxl basic search

Tags: python, xlsx, openpyxl

I am trying to search an excel document and if the name of the mp3 file is matched in the excel document, It prints out the row the instance of the name is found on.

this is what I have:

```
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import glob
import re
import os
for name in glob.glob('*.mp3'):
  audio = EasyID3(name)
  wb = load_workbook('xl.xlsx')
  sh = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Russian')
  for row in sh:
    if row.value == name:
      print row.number
```

Comment: Please consider [*improving your question*](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise)

Comment: And? What's your question?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are loading the workbook and finding the sheet for every `.mp3` file. Move that code outside of the loop.

Second problem is that you try to iterate over the worksheet `sh`, which is not iterable.

Third problem is that you test `row.value` to equal name, where you probably want `sh.cell[0].value`

Your code should probably look more like:

```
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import glob
import re
import os
wb = load_workbook('xl.xlsx')
sh = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Russian')
for name in glob.glob('*.mp3'):
    audio = EasyID3(name)
    for row_index in range(sh.get_highest_row()):
        if sh.cell(row=row_index, column=0).value == name:
            print(row_index)
```

As @Bill Kidd indicated, in openpyxl 2.4.2 you'll have to replace `.get_highest_row()` by `.max_row` (no braces!).

Comment: Anthon's answer is mostly correct.
In "if row.cell(row=row_index, column=0).value == name:"
Replace "row.cell" with "sh.cell", because there is no row object.

Additionally replace "print row.number" with "print(row_index)" for the same reason.

In openpyxl 2.4.2 there is no Worksheet method "get_highest_row()", use the property "max_row" instead.

Comment: Worksheets are iterable as rows.